# Run a WP-CLI command from within PHP without using shell_exec()

Tags: php, wp-cli

Is there another way for me to run a WP-CLI command from within a PHP script other than using the `shell_exec()` function.

Comment: What command are you trying to run?

Comment: I'm trying to run a custom command which contains a wp-cli script that I created.  The script needs to run as a cron job and it needs to run server side as if it doesn't it will time out and it will cause the initial page load on the cron run to be very slow (due to the way that WordPress manages cron jobs).

Answer (score 0):

If it's a script you created, then move the function outside of WP CLI, where both WP CLI and your PHP script can access, and then have your WP CLI command run that function.

Comment: I like where this is going.  However, it's a php function that is run on a scheduled WordPress cron event that runs a WP-CLI command and it must be run via WP-CLI because it uses native WordPress functions.